# Calculate height of PivotItem?

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

The following is a very basic layout for a Windows Phone 8 app. I've got a `PivotControl` with a `PivotItem`. The header of the `PivotControl` is outlined in red, while the `PivotItem` is outlined in green. I'm going to have a `Canvas` taking up 100% of the `PivotItem` so I need to be able to calculate it's dimensions accordingly (because that height/width will determine the size and placement of other controls).

So right now I can calculate the width of my `PivotItem` with this, where `margin` is the amount of margin on all four sides (multiplied by 2 for the left and right):

```
double width = Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth - (margin * 2);
```

The height is more difficult because I need to take the total screen height and subtract the StatusBar height, and the header height (red rectangle in my image).

Does anyone know how I can get the height of my `PivotItem`? Is there an easier way than trying to calculate it like I am? Right now the `Height` and `ActualHeight` properties are both 0.0.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a Canvas occupying the whole PivotItem? Something like this:

```
<phone:Pivot>
    <phone:Pivot.Items>
        <phone:PivotItem Header="menu">
            <Canvas x:Name="Canvas" />
        </phone:PivotItem>
        <phone:PivotItem Header="game" />
    </phone:Pivot.Items>
</phone:Pivot>
```

If so, retrieving the height of the canvas is quite straightforward:

```
Debug.WriteLine(this.Canvas.ActualHeight);
```

Note: the `ActualHeight` property won't be populated before the `Loaded` event. So if you're trying to read it from the constructor or the `OnNavigatedTo` method, the property will be equal to 0.

The full XAML code:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
    x:Class="WP7ForumTest.Page3"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    Loaded="Page_Loaded">

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <phone:Pivot>
                <phone:Pivot.Items>
                    <phone:PivotItem Header="menu">
                        <Canvas x:Name="Canvas" />
                    </phone:PivotItem>
                    <phone:PivotItem Header="game" />
                </phone:Pivot.Items>
            </phone:Pivot>
        </Grid>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

And the code-behind:

```
private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(this.Canvas.ActualHeight.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. That might work, but I'd really prefer to calculate the height before the `Loaded` event because when the page is loading, some things depend on that height/width. Maybe I am going about this wrong though - I'll take a look at it again tonight and see if I can make this solution work.

Comment: @lhan16 I highly doubt there's a way to dynamically get the size of the elements before the `Loaded` event. If that's an issue, you'll have to hardcode the values like Lance suggested, or use a different container like `Grid` which will allow you to position the elements with percentages instead of pixel values.

Answer (score 1):

The default height and width will change depending on the phone's resolution. Here are the pivot item template sizes according to Blend.

WVGA (480x800): 456 x 603

WXGA (480x1280): 456 x 603

720p (720x1280): 456 x 656

Comment: Thanks. I will give this a try tonight. However, I'd really prefer a way to actually calculate those values so that I don't have to hard-code them in for each resolution.